# The blank space above font ascender line in TextBlock

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I found there was a space at the top of TextBlock, above the line of ascender (as the red arrow shows in picture), even when TextBlock.VerticalAlignment = Top, Padding=0 and TextBlock.Height = Auto. 
Does someone know why there has an additional space? Is there any ways to remove it without specify absolute value of TextBlock.Height and TextBlock.Margin?

Here is the XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Height="Auto" FontWeight="Light" Text="aps" FontSize="100" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" />
        <TextBlock Height="Auto" FontWeight="Light" Text="Sphinx" FontSize="100" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Screenshot : http://i.stack.imgur.com/LAk95.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The space is the result of **line spacing**. One solution can be setting additional properties of `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock LineHeight="80" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
```

However, you have to compute the LineHeight yourself and it will vary from font to font and between sizes, but it's the easiest way of placing the text at the exact desired line. If this is not acceptable, now that you know the root of the problem you can look for a more general solution.